# static public member function ( C++ )

Tags: c++

I need to count the times my public member function creates new data in a loop.
Each time data is read it is saved into a private member varaible. Nothing is overwritten.

```
// my classType.h
const int ImpliedIndex = 1000;

class classType
{
private:
  char privateMember[ImpliedIndex];
  char privateMember2[ImpliedIndex];
public:
  static void myMemberCounter;
  void printMyInformation():
  void mySupplier(const char[] );
  ...
};

//classType.cpp
int globalCounter = 0;

void classType::printMyInformation()
{
   ...
   cout << privateMember << endl;
   cout << globalCounter++ << endl;
}
void classType::mySupplier( const char buff[] )
{
   strcpy( privateMember, buff );

}

// The main should clear things up a bit.
// main.cpp

int main()
{
    while ( !inFile.eof() )
    {   
        for ( int x = 0; x < 20; x++ )
        {
       // do file I/O here
       // save each line of file into an temp array
       // supply temp array with a routine defined in myClass
       // re-use temp array until we run out of file
        }
    }    
//close file
```

I need to change my 20 to a variable. Notice that in classType I used globalCounter to retrieve the number of types.

What I wanted to do is, `globalCounter = memberCounter;`

But I have to re-declare both of these varaibles, and I can't use `myClass[ImpliedIndex].memberCounter` with the assignment operator (=) or the binary insertion operator(<<).

Comment: I can't really understand what you are trying to do, please try to explain more clearly what is your end goal

Comment: Adding pseudocode describing what is to be done inside the loop would be useful too.

Comment: I agree.  I'm not sure why a static class member wouldn't solve your problem.  Perhaps more description?

Comment: Please post code that compiles.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
static void myMemberCounter;
```

Should generate a compile-time error. It looks like a variable, but has type `void`, which doesn't make sense.

If you want a static ("class variable") counter, you should use a type like `int`. Then it would be easy for the class to use that counter to count the number of instances, by just incrementing the counter in the constructor. The count can be read by the outside world by adding a `public` class function to return it.